# How to make a validation in react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I try to make validation with react-hook-form v7 but there are several errors. First I tried it connect to Reactstrap but it is impossible since v7. Then I change it to react-bootstrap.

My first problem is how to do it that first I do validation and if all it is correct then I fetch the date to API (I use next's and contact form work).

I had idea to use `onChange={handel(on submit)} onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}`

Secondly problem is to show errors. I make it like that but not show the errors, but the form respons to that.

```
 <div id="phone" isRequired className="m-t-15">
            <Control             style={{width: "100%"}}  name="phone"
{...register("Mobile number", {
              required: {
                value: true,
                message: "Numer telefonu jest obowiązkowy, zebysmy mogli sie skontaktować"
              }, 
              pattern: {
                value: /^[0-9+-]+$/,
                message: "Dozwolone sa wylacznie cyfry"
              }, 
              minLength: {
                value: 9,
                message: "Numer telefonu jest za krótki"
              }, 
              maxLength: {
                value: 15,
                message: "Numer telefonu jest za długi"
              }})}

placeholder="Wpisz swój telefon"  type="tel" value={phone} onChange={(e) => { setPhone(e.target.value) }} />

    <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="phone">
        {({ messages }) => {
          console.log(messages);
          return (
            messages &&
            Object.entries(messages).map(([type, message]) => (
              <p key={type}>{message}</p>
            ))
          );
        }}
      </ErrorMessage>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use error message validation like react-hook-form [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Applyvalidation)

```
<input type="tel" value={phone} {...register("phone", { required: true })} />
{errors.phone?.type === 'required' && "Numer telefonu jest obowiązkowy, zebysmy mogli sie skontaktować"}
```